# Any shortcut for joining 2 lines to 1 line with ; as delimiter in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to take a file with lines that that looks like this:

```
diff
patt1 = patt[0];
diff1
patt2 = patt[1];
```

to and transform it to this:

```
diff patt1 = patt[0];
diff patt2 = patt[1];
```

`gq` works for single line.
but I want to do it for many lines with `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the significance of the `;` at the end is, but many variants are possible with

```
:g/<pattern>/j
```

If you want to join every even-numbered line in the buffer to the odd-numbered line above it, you could use

```
:g/^/j
```

since `^` matches on every line.  If you want to join every line ending in `;` to the line above it, then

```
:2,$g/;$/-j
```

is basically right, although it might surprise you sometimes.  If you want to join enough lines so that every new line (except possible the last) will end with a `;`, then try

```
:g/;\@<!$/.,/;$\|\%$/j
```

should do it, although it might give an error message on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of lines to be joined and they are not all contiguous I might do something like this:

- `qakJq` - define macro `a` to move up a line and join it
- `g/;$/normal@a` - run that command on all lines ending with `;`

Answer (score 0):

Use following command:

```
:%g/;\@<!$/j
```